# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\coil-20-unproc\\obj1_0.png'

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I am trying to divide the image dataset into train and test. For this I am copying the images from one folder to other in python. For this I have given the address of both source and destination. But the problem arises when it displays the above error. It can not find the image files to copy. Although I have given correct image address which is "C:\Users\DELL\coil-20-unproc\imagename". Still can't copy the images

```
original_dataset_dir=r"C:\Users\DELL\coil-20-unproc"
# Copy object1 images to train_obj1_dir
fnames = ['obj1_{}.png'.format(i) for i in range(0,72)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_obj1_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter notebook and Jupyter lab refer to relative path from location that it was started up. You can try these

1. Copy the file to your startup directory.
   (You could enter `!pwd` in a cell and execute to find put your startup directory)
2. Create a link from a file in your startup directory to that file.